# React-Navigation: StackActions.pop cannot be mocked because it is not a function

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I am trying to mock a `pop` function of `StackAction` from `react-navigation` so that it can be tested using jest, but somehow it is throwing error

```
import { StackActions } from 'react-navigation'

const popSpy = jest.spyOn(StackActions, 'pop')
```

Error says

```
Cannot spy the pop property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

When I try to print StackActions object in console, it just shows `push`, `reset`, and `replace`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have already mocked the `StackActions` object somewhere with incomplete list of properties since all the methods in the log are mock functions.

So the issue is wherever you're mocking it, you need to add the missing methods.

However, mocking `StackActions` methods doesn't make sense. They only return objects and don't do anything else. You probably want to mock `navigation.pop`/`navigation.dispatch` instead. But it's unrelated to this question.

Comment: In component code I have used `const popAction = StackActions.pop({n: 3,})` hence whenever I am calling that method from my testcase it gives error, so I thought to simply mock it and check whether that has been called or not

Comment: But yes, that's right it was mocked in setup file itself by my colleague, thanks a lot for that hint.